# ErrorException Undefined array key 0 in php artisan serve

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, laravel-8

every time I hit php artisan serve, after working for a few seconds, this error is constantly displayed

```
  ErrorException

  Undefined array key 0

  at D:\Request\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:266
    262▕             } elseif (str($line)->contains(' Closing')) {
    263▕                 $requestPort = $this->getRequestPortFromLine($line);
    264▕                 $request = $this->requestsPool[$requestPort];
    265▕
  ➜ 266▕                 [$startDate, $file] = $request;
    267▕
    268▕                 $formattedStartedAt = $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    269▕
    270▕                 unset($this->requestsPool[$requestPort]);

  1   D:\Request\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:266
      Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\{closure}("Undefined array key 0", "D:\Request\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php")

  2   D:\Request\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Collections\Traits\EnumeratesValues.php:236
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand::Illuminate\Foundation\Console\{closure}("[Thu Feb  2 15:43:40 2023] 192.168.2.50:54933 Closing")
```

please guide me

```
if(isset($this->requestsPool[$requestPort]))
{
    $request = $this->requestsPool[$requestPort];
}
```

Even after adding this line, the problem was not solved

a am also try

```
return isset($matches[1]) ? Carbon::createFromFormat('D M d H:i:s Y', $matches[1]) : Carbon::now();
```

But it still gives a new error

```
   TypeError

  Illegal offset type

  at D:\Request\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:254
    250▕                 $this->serverRunningHasBeenDisplayed = true;
    251▕             } elseif (str($line)->contains(' Accepted')) {
    252▕                 $requestPort = $this->getRequestPortFromLine($line);
    253▕
  ➜ 254▕                 $this->requestsPool[$requestPort] = [
    255▕                     $this->getDateFromLine($line),
    256▕                     false,
    257▕                 ];
    258▕             } elseif (str($line)->contains([' [200]: GET '])) {

  1   D:\Request\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Collections\Traits\EnumeratesValues.php:236
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand::Illuminate\Foundation\Console\{closure}("[Thu Feb  2 16:03:21 2023] 192.168.2.50:58365 Accepted")

  2   D:\Request\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:292
      Illuminate\Support\Collection::each(Object(Closure))
```

Comment: You try to change code in vendor directory?

Comment: Thank you for your response
I only have this file
\vendor\laravel\ui\auth-backend\AuthenticatesUsers.php
I changed
And I changed it a little like this
public function showLoginForm()
    {
        $user = User::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

        return view('auth.login',['user' => $user]);
    }

Comment: You must never not change files in vendor directory. rm -rf vendor, composer install - and all will work.